# How to get the dynamic script id

Tags: javascript

```
var id="sel"+i;
var inner='<td><selec id="item">'+'<option>'+data.stateLevelHierarchy.Mla[j].name+'</option>'+'</select></td><td id='+id+'></td>';
```

how to get the td id in javascript and how can i append button to td id dynamically.can any one help me..

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery, you can easily get the attribute value of any HTML element.

**Try this it will work :**

Give the outer `td` some class. then try something like that

```
<td class="outertd"><select id="item">'+'<option>'+data.stateLevelHierarchy.Mla[j].name+'</option>'+'</select></td><td id='+id+'></td>

var tdid = $('.outertd td').attr('id');
console.log(tdid);
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y96d03mx/2/

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: but here i created the table in plain javascript,how can get the id?

Comment: I updated the Jsfiddle and its working fine now. You have to append that variable inside html element as i am doing appending var into `<div id="getTable">` div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").find(".outered").attr("id");
```

try this

Comment: refer my question i generated the script dynamically from that script to get the td id.

Comment: for(var j=0;j<data.stateLevelHierarchy.Mla.length;j++)  
       {
       var id="sel"+i;
       var inner='<td class="outered"><select id="item">'+
           '<option>'+data.stateLevelHierarchy.Mla[j].name+'</option>'+
           '</select></td><td id='+id+'></td>';
          
       }

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: $("td").find(".outered").attr("id");

Comment: no,i created the td id in plain javascript,i think its not going to work out.

Comment: try console.log($("td").find(".outered")) what it return

Comment: its giving undefined

Comment: it strange when you create td element on page load?

Comment: no,i creating the td id after click on div i am creating the td id not at page loading.

Comment: can you give me the block in which you handle click event

Comment: for(var j=0;j<data.stateLevelHierarchy.Mla.length;j++)  
       {
       var id="sel"+i;
       var inner='<td class="outered"><select id="item">'+
           '<option>'+data.stateLevelHierarchy.Mla[j].name+'</option>'+
           '</select></td><td id='+id+'></td>';
          console.log($("td").find(".outered").attr("id"));
       }

Comment: i need event handle block like $(".add").on("click",function(){console.log("Some Action"); })

Comment: did you try $(this) in event handler callback

Comment: no,can you please look at my code once,i will send join.me look once.

Comment: bro i want to know from where the click event happen so i can  help you easily

Comment: <div class="Folder" onclick="getCandidates(' + responsedata[j].cdegid + ',\'' + responsedata[j].designationName + '\')">'+responsedata[j].designationName+'</div>

Comment: are you using jquery or vanilla javascript ?

Comment: inside this div <td> created dynamically

Comment: configure with jquery than i will able to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
//Using plain JS:
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
button.id = "Button";
button.name = "Button"; 
button.innerHTML = "Button";
document.getElementById(id).appendChild(button);
```

Comment: assuming that var id is the 'id' of the dynamically added td